# Is it possible to multiply initialize using open mp in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I have a for loop which access many memory pointers in each iteration. For each of these memory pointers, I created an index. My problem is that when I try to use open mp to parallelize this loop, I get the following error:

error: expected iteration declaration or initialization

I thought that this error would be one of the following:

-Open MP does not accept increment different than ++ or --
-Open MP does not accept multiple initialization in a loop

For reasons regarding performance, it is important to me to use these multiple indexes. Does anybody know the answer for my problem?

Here it is the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
{
    int tID = omp_get_thread_num();
    int i, iCF, iPF, iNF, iPJG, iCJG, iNJG, iPRJG, iCRJG;

    ##pragma omp for nowait
    for(i=0, iCF=0, iPF=0, iNF=sqrBcksDim, iPJG=0, iCJG=0, iNJG=sqrBcksSize, iPRJG=0, iCRJG=0 ; iCF<RHSArraySize ; iPF=iCF, iCF=iNF, iNF+=sqrBcksDim, iPJG=iCJG, iCJG=iNJG, iNJG+=sqrBcksSize, iPRJG=iCRJG, iCRJG+=rectBcksSize, ++i)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The OpenMP rules about what’s legal in a `for` loop in C++ are on page 40 of this specification: http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf.  The short answer is, no.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at that third clause, you’re doing a lot of inherently sequential computations that depend on the program state at the end of the previous iteration of the loop.  You could move all of those operations but the += and ++ updates inside the body of the loop, and from the look of things possibly make the loop condition depend on iNF, correct?  But some of them look like they still might be `ordered`.  For a parallel algorithm, are there closed-form initializers you could use inside the loop body that depend only on `i` or something loop-invariant?

If not, and the inputs to each iteration really do depend on the results of previous iterations of the loop, then it’s not a parallel algorithm

**One suggestion:**

Here’s how I would try to fix this.  You can only initialize `i` and increment it by a constant within the loop; however, you can equivalently move all the rest of those operations *inside* the loop.  For example, I don’t know what else goes on inside the loop body, but if `iCF` is initialized to 0, `iNF` to `sqrBcksDim` and at the end of each iteration, `iCF` is set to the previous value of `iNF` and `iNF` is incremented by `sqrBcksDim`, it looks like you could rewrite the loop into something like:

```
int i;

#pragma omp for nowait
for ( i=0; i < RHSArraySize/sqrBcksDim; ++i )
{
  const int iCF = i*sqrBcksDim;
  const int iNF = iCF + sqrBcksDim;
  // ...
}
```

Can you do that for your other variables?  If you really have a parallel algorithm here, you should be able to, because each run of the loop should only depend on i and loop invariants, which you can use in your initializers.  You’ll need to declare a variable outside the loop if you’re going to refer to it outside the body of the loop, but for the time being, just declare a new local variable and don’t read any variable outside the loop that you also write to inside the loop.  If there are no implicit sequential dependencies, you should be able to initialize them all at the start of the loop body.

You might not end up doing it that way, but it might help you think about how to refactor.

Comment: Yes, this idea works. It turns out that I created a class with these parameters, so that each core access its parameters through its thread ID. Thank you guys